search variable name in a range adn assign its value
I'm beginning to modify an Excel VBA to get it localized in different languages.
I'm going on the solution of assigning a variable to the caption.value and assign the value of the variable according to the desired language.



Language
FR
EN




Ln_Date
Date
Date


Ln_Created by
Créé par
Created by



And in my example, with th language set priorly, I would like to give to each variable (name in the firdst column) its value.
The question is, do I have to set the variable first (public ln_Date as string) and after search its value in the first column and assign its value (variable = range(variable_name + offset(language),1).Text)
Or is the a possibility the create on the fly while searching the range the variable with their type (public string) and their value ?
I'm trying for each variable defined priorly to search in the range and assign its value but as the program advance in its developpement, the function is becoming more and more big/complex and it seems to me that it is not the best way to do things as I have to add loops for each new language variable..
It seems like a maze in the end

Why do you need variables for that?

The idea is that as I have to use this text in the correct language at several position in the excel file and in the differnet forms, I want to be able to assign the text according to the language to a variable and after call this variable in my UserForm_Initialize for example : UserForm.Caption = Ln_Title and with this at one position I define the value of the title of the form and everytime I open the form the correct language is assigned (well it may not be the best solution but i think it is the less code consuming)

There is no way to access the name of a variable during runtime, so you code would look like this (I guess you want to set named ranges for all the variables?)
Dim Ln_Date As String
Ln_Date = range("Ln_Date" + offset(language), 1).Text
(... and so on for every variable)

You might think about using a Collection or Dictionary instead.
My suggestion is not to read the translated words into variables but to create a small function that provides a the wanted text whenever it is needed. The easiest variation could look like this (I assume that the translation table is on a separate sheet called Translations - change that to your needs).
Function getLanguageColumn(language As String) As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Translations")
        Dim col As Long
        On Error Resume Next
        col = Application.Match(language, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Translations").Rows(1), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If col = 0 Then col = 2         ' Default: First column
    End With
    getLanguageColumn = col
End Function

Function getTranslation(code As String, language As String)
    Dim col As Long
    col = getLanguageColumn(language)

    Dim translation As String
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Translations")
        On Error Resume Next
        translation = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(code, .UsedRange, col, False)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If translation = "" Then translation = "Can't translate code " & code
    End With
    getTranslation = translation 
End Function

There is room for improvement (better error handling, cashing the translation table into an array or dictionary), but as long as the table doesn't get too large, it will do.
Then, in your code you call the function whenever you need a translated term. For example, you create a Sub in a user form called SetLabels and call that routine when the form is displayed (UserForm_Activate()) or when the user changes the language if you give them the option to chose.
Dim Language As String

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Language = "FR"
    SetLabels
End If

Sub SetLabels
    Me.LabelDate = getTranslation("LN_Date", Language)
    Me.LabelCreatedBy = getTranslation("Ln_Created by", Language)
    (...)
End Sub


Thanks for your detailed explanation, Black cat thought of the same solution with dictionnary, i've never used this element. I'll check with it, thanks a lot

You could implement the getTranslation-function with a Dictionary if you want (or if the function gets too slow). It's a design principle in programming that the calling code (eg in your form) doesn't care about how the function works. Dictionaries are really powerful and I use them often, so if you are interested, dig into it. I recommend https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrGchDgF3m4, but you can find lots of resources that explain it.

This workaround of the problem uses Scripting.Dictionary The result is not a real variable rather an item of the dictionary object where you can refer to an item with the predefined name from your table.
This is the table of the languages on Sheet1



Variables
EN
FR
DE
IT
SK




Var1
en1
fr1
de1
it1
sk1


Var2
en2
fr2
de2
it2
sk2


Var3
en3
fr3
de3
it3
sk3


Var4
en4
fr4
de4
it4
sk4


Var5
en5
fr5
de5
it5
sk5



This is the Sub to define the Dictionary.
Sub ActLang()
lang = "IT" 'GetLanguage  'this is a sub or to get the actual language in lang
Set ws = Worksheets("sheet1")    'the sheet where the language table is set.
Set found = ws.Range("A1:F1").Find(lang)
Dim varcoll As Scripting.dictionary
Set varcoll = New Scripting.dictionary

For i = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    varcoll.Add ws.Cells(i, 1).Value, ws.Cells(i, found.Column).Value
Next i

End Sub

After running this Sub you can refer to a "variable" like this:
varcoll.Item("Var4") or varcoll("Var4")
Sidenote: The Item parameter is case-sensitive.
